# Unable to access service by service name in Openshift v3 cluster

Tags: service-discovery, openshift-origin, openshift-enterprise

I have two services deployed in Openshift Enterprise V3. Say the services are

1. Service Name - A, Namespace - ns1
2. Service Name - B, Namespace - ns2

When I am trying to access service B from a pod/container under service A with the url http://B.ns2.svc.cluster.local, it tells me that "Could not resolve host; Name of Service not known". Also I get the same message for kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
I am able to access the service using the static IP address for service B

Any help/suggestion would be appreciated on this. Is there any way I can see the DNS entries for all the services that are created in Openshift environment

Comment: Is service B exposed by a router?

Comment: Both the services are exposed by routes and accessible outside openshift.  Service B is not accessible using the routes from pod under service A, only accessible using the static IP.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is solved. At a high level it has been solved by adding/enabling dns server in the master and node machines. I followed the steps mentioned in http://developers.redhat.com/blog/2015/11/19/dns-your-openshift-v3-cluster/ to enable custom dns in master and node machines with only difference is, I had to keep the following entry instead of "127.0.0.1:8053" as mentioned in the link

dnsConfig:

bindAddress: 0.0.0.0:8053